# find a basis of the annihilator of a subspace defined by vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

$U$ is a subspace in $\Bbb R^5$ defined by:

$$u_1=(0,1,2,-1,0)$$
$$u_2=(1,6,-3,0,2)$$
$$u_3=(4,-2,0,1,-1)$$

Find a basis for the annihilator of $U$.

Not sure how to use the span of these three vectors to find the annihilator of subspace.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An annihilator of $U$ means a solution of equation
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x_2+2x_3-x_4=0 \\
x_1+6x_2-3x_3+2x_5=0 \\
4x_1-2x_2+x_4-x_5=0
\end{array}\right.$$
And you can use row echelon form to solve it.

Comment: there are 3 equations and 5 variables. how can it be solved? can you explain it please?